# $.getJSON в Windows Phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, mobile, windows-phone-7

Приветствую всех!

Делаю маленькую утилитку, на wp7, android, ios.

На android и ios - `$.getJSON` - срабатывает отлично, как с локальными файлами json, так и который расположены на другом сервере. В WP7 проблема: не работает метод. После долгой хоть бы по гуглу - ничего путного не попалось.

Может кто сталкивался, в чем может быть проблема?

Заранее огромное спасибо.

Comment: попробуйте дебаггер какой-нить. например jsconsole.com для тестирования приложений на разных девайсах удобная вещь. есть и другие, с разными возможностями...
[тут][1] видео от автора.

[1]:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DSH392Gxaho

Comment: он не работает только в wp7. Код полностью сам по себе работоспособный.

Comment: ну так надо понять на каком моменте валится. откройте эту консоль, вручную методы погоняйте, посмотрите ошибки если есть которые возвращает $.getJSON или лучше сразу $.ajax...

Comment: дело в том, что читал на буржуйских сайта, что тут нужно колдовать с методом $.getJSON, т.к. WP7 - это IE. И у него с ним проблемы.

Comment: Говорят нужно юзать $.ajax - попробывал, но все равно 0.

Comment: пробывал подключение Zepto.js - тоже безрезультатно.

Answer (score 1):

Преобразовать обычный текст в json можно банальным `eval`. Попробуйте получить json текст с помощью `$.ajax`, а потом пропустить через `eval`, мб прокатит.

Алсо, кто ищет, тот всегда найдет: [Using $.getJSON in a WP7 PhoneGap (Cordova) app (v1.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722826/using-getjson-in-a-wp7-phonegap-cordova-app-v1-5)

А вообще, как попал на топик 10 летней давности, не знаю. Само так вышло :-)